# Selecting values of a column from a join based on dates - With Tables and Code

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I posted a similar question earlier but I thought I'd post again with some additional info.

Basically what I need to do is pull values into a dataset that are based off of dates, and I need a unique value for each customer. Each customer has a product they are on, and a product they will automatically roll on at renewal.

If their renewal date greater than today, I need to return the product they are on today. If their renewal date is less than today, I need to pull in their renewal product.

The finished product should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
FIELD1 VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,FIELD2 VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL
,FIELD3 VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL
,FIELD4 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3,FIELD4) VALUES 
('custid','product','category','enddate');
INSERT INTO mytable(FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3,FIELD4) VALUES  
('1','FlexLife','H','01/01/2060');
INSERT INTO mytable(FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3,FIELD4) VALUES 
('2','whoellife12','R','06/08/2019');
```

Here is kind of what the first data set looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
FIELD1 VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
INSERT INTO mytable(FIELD1) VALUES ('custid');
INSERT INTO mytable(FIELD1) VALUES ('1');
INSERT INTO mytable(FIELD1) VALUES ('2');
```

And this should be joined with this dataset to achieve the result:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
FIELD1 VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,FIELD2 VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,FIELD3 VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL
,FIELD4 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3,FIELD4) VALUES   
('custid','product','category','enddate');
INSERT INTO mytable(FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3,FIELD4) VALUES    
('1','wholelife12','R','02/07/2019');
INSERT INTO mytable(FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3,FIELD4) VALUES    
('2','powerlife12','R','06/08/2019');
INSERT INTO mytable(FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3,FIELD4) VALUES    
('1','flexlife','H','01/01/2060');
INSERT INTO mytable(FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3,FIELD4) VALUES    
('2','flexlife','H','1/1/2060');
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: It would probably have been better to edit your first question.  Now, perhaps you should delete it in favor of this one?

Comment: The structure is unusual, wouldn't this be easier if FIELD4 was a date rather than VARCHAR?

Comment: Also right now all dates are greater > today, did you mean perhaps 06/08/2018 for the date?

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant @Ian-Fogelman

Comment: I put it in an auto-generator at the advice of a mod and this is what came out. @Degan

Comment: The problem doesn't make a lot of sense. Does each customer has always 2 records? One for each product? Can we have a customer where both products have a past date? Can we have a customer with two future dates in both products?